# Why is datatable cdn not working on table generated from ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

The datatable cdn is not working with a table that I call from another page using ajax. The new table gets generated, but it does not show the other features of the datatable in the table, and only show table on the page.

I have made a page which has a button, which calls a function that refreshes the table by ajax. I put the cdn datatable links and codes on the other page which is working fine when opened directly, but when called from ajax it doesn't show the datatable cdn function. Instead, the whole table is shown.

```js
$(function() {
 $('#populate').click(function() {
  $.ajax
    ({
     type: "POST",
     url: "getPurchaseInvoice.php",
     data: $('#frm3').serialize(),
     success: function(data)
     {
      $('.example').html(data);
     }
    });
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%" border="1" class="example"  data-page-length="25">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>Invoice No.</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Total Amount</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $inc;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['hrm_inv_no'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['fdate'];?></td>
    <td><?php if($row['hrm_vendor_name'] != ''){ echo $row['hrm_vendor_name']; } else { echo "Other"; }?></td>
    <?php /*?><td><?php echo $row['hrm_vendor_name'];?></td><?php */?>
    <td><?php echo $row['hrm_net_value'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><a class="iframef"  href="purchaseinvoice.php?actiontype=print&id=<?php echo $row['hrm_inv_no'];?>"><img src="images/print.png"  alt="Print"></a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;<img  id="itemdel" title="Delete" onclick="deletePos('<?php echo $row['hrm_inv_no'];?>')" src="images/b_drop.png" style="cursor:pointer" alt="Delete"></td>
  </tr>
  <?php $inc++; 

}

/*header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Purchase-Invoice-".date('Y-m-d').".xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");  
header("Expires: 0");  
  */
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tableexport/jszip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
         {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                 text: 'Save Excel',
                title: 'Purchase Invoice',
                customize: function( xlsx ) {
                var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                $('row:first c', sheet).attr( 's', '42' );
            }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                 text: 'Save Pdf',
                title: 'Purchase Invoice'
            }
       ]
    } );
} );
</script>

    
<div id="purchaseInvoice">
<table style="width:100%" border="1" class="example"  data-page-length="25">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>Invoice No.</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Total Amount</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>   
  </div>
```

Comment: Please use some punctuation. It is very hard to figure out what the question is about if you write it in a single, long sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is good, you would like to load a php page containing a Datatable providing some data.

If so, the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method should be appropriate.

```
$('.example').load( "getPurchaseInvoice.php", $('#frm3').serialize());
```